# проблема с curl и ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl

скачал версию ubuntu 22.04.3 (последняя) хочу запустить данную команду:

```sh
curl -L https://tljh.jupyter.org/bootstrap.py | sudo -E python3 - --admin <admin-user-name>
```

должен установить tljh, но выдается ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

уже пробывал удалять и скачивать curl, памяти хватает, делал `apt autoremove`, пробывал вызывать от root через `sudo su`.

Comment: При чём тут curl если у вас питона нет?

Comment: это тоже странно потому что питон я установил (python3 и python3-dev)

Comment: для `curl` ненужно `sudo` ; команда whereis python` что показывает?

Comment: [специфичная проблема установки в виртуалке](https://askubuntu.com/a/1449425)

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос закрыт. Просто создал новую виртуальную машину и начал все с чистого листа и все заработало.